# Flow - chatter post as community user not working

Tags: community, visual-workflow, chatter, chatter-groups, customer-community-plus

I have a flow that create a chatter post on a chatter group. The flow works well when an internal user triggers it but when i login as a community user i get the error "You don't have the rights to perform this operation".
Does anyone know where to look? thanks!

Comment: can you check if profile has  the 'Run Flows' option enabled

Comment: Hi @SaiPraveenKakkirala, yes it is enabled.

Comment: Did you try debugging the flow as that user?

Comment: I tried but the field i need to modify isn't on the debug layout, this is another topic i try to solve.

Comment: Can you try debugging that by removing the start condition so we can understand where exactly the issue is

Comment: I tried to debug, same error message, nothing else.

Comment: Error Occurred:

Vous n'êtes pas autorisé(e) à effectuer cette opération. (French)

Comment: Which element are you getting the error?

Comment: On my action "Post to chatter". It works correctly with an internal user.

Comment: can you check this [limitation](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdyTLUAZ/allow-guest-user-to-post-to-chatter-insert-feeditem-records) I guess this might be the reason

Comment: Oh, didn't see this one... ok i see. Kinda frustrating! Thank you for your help tho :)

Comment: Sure will post the same as Answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a work around: instead of using the post a chatter action, i insert a feeditem. It works but correctly but doesn't push an in-app notification, i need to figure why.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments you were getting the error in the flow in `post to chatter` element. I see this is a kind of limitation. Please find the [idea](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdyTLUAZ/allow-guest-user-to-post-to-chatter-insert-feeditem-records) which is logged for the same

Comment: I found a work around: instead of using the post a chatter action, i insert a feeditem. It works but correctly but doesn't push an in-app notification, i need to figure why.